Continuous dependence of the solution on the data constant
Considering $Lu=f$ to be a linear symmetric self-adjoint problem with L being a differential operator of order $2m$, the book finite element book by Strang and Fix claims that
$$ ||u||_{2m} \leq C ||f||_0 $$
holds with $C>0$ independent of $u$.
I was able to find such a statement in the book by Evans but only for second order problems. Also I would like to explicitly compute such a constant $C$.
Are there ways to compute the constant $C$ and where can I find the estimate proved for an operator of order $2m$?
